# Modifying param key to use query twice in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I'm using Ransack to run search on my app. I've got a search bar that users input text to, the  text is passed to a search controller where I search for the query in two tables: Posts and Groups

The problem is that I want to run the query on `:name` and `:title` for Groups and Posts respectively and then serve both sets of results on the same page. The search form uses :name_cont and so I am trying to copy the hash that this form sends to the controller and change the key to :title_cont when I run the same search on Posts.

Don't hesitate to ask for clarification.

**Search Controller**

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @q = Group.search(params[:q])
    @groups = @q.result
    @group_count = @groups.count

    #query = params[:q][:name_cont]
    posthash = { :q => {:title_cont => params[:q][:name_cont]} }
    @q = Post.search(posthash)
    @posts_results = @q.result(:distinct => true)
    @post_count = @posts.count

  end
end
```

**Search Form:**

```
=search_form_for @q, :url => { :controller => "search", :action => "index" }do |f|
  =f.text_field :name_cont
  =f.submit 'search'
```

**Error that it yields:**

```
undefined method `name_cont' for #<Ransack::Search:0x007fc0f798df18>
```

**UPDATE 1:**

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @q = Group.search(params[:q])
    @groups = @q.result
    @group_count = @groups.count

    #I am trying to take the query, i.e. the "value" in params[:q]
    #and pass it into a new hash to use as a parameter in 'search'
    posthash = { :q => {:title_cont => params[:q][:name_cont]} }

    @q2 = Post.search(posthash)
    @posts_results = @q2.result(:distinct => true)
    @post_count = @posts.count

  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overriding `@q` for searching posts, which responds to title not to name, eventually the search form gets an object that doesn't have `name_cont` but `title_cont` instead, so you need to use another variable name for searching posts other than `@q`.

Comment: Awesome, that solves the `name_cont` error. However, I still can't figure out how to share that query between two calls to the `search` method in the search controller, which takes hashes as its parameter

Comment: `search` method just expects a hash, so you can pass the second search a hash like this `Post.search({:title_cont => params[:q][:name_cont]})`.

Comment: that works. you're a saint. Thank you. I also was messing up my instance variables-last line of the controller